# Finding the volume of an irregular object of less density

Tags: measurements, volume

I have a problem that is not taught to us at school, but I wish to know the solution of it.

The problem is:
how can one find the volume of an irregular object by an eureka vessel (or any other method if impossible), where the object floats on the surface of the fluid?

Also is there any other way to find the volume of a partially immersed irregular object besides a eureka vessel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Push the object under the water for an rough measurement. Or for a more accurate measurement, attach a weight that is heavy enough to pull the object under the water, measure their combined volume, then measure the volume of the weight on its own and subtract that from the combined volume.

Comment: thanksforyourhelpgandalf61!

Answer (score 1):

Gandalf61's method of attaching a heavy weight is good, you could also try using a less dense liquid (e.g. alcohol) so that the object will sink.

Use a measuring cylinder to catch the liquid displaced and use thin cotton to lower and pull out the objects.

There might well be a modern method soon whereby a laser or ultrasound scans the object, makes a 3D image that can be shown on a screen, rotated etc.  That could give the volume and perhaps surface area.  If it doesn't exist yet, it's probably close.

On a visit to an orthodontist recently, to help someone with their brace - it was a surprise to see that instead of using a plastic mould they now use a camera/scanner put in the mouth and rotated that makes the 3D image described.

That data was used to make the life size 'retainer' that patients often wear at night after the main brace is finished with.